# Using applescript to edit a server variable

Tags: email, variables, outlook, applescript

I do not know if I am asking this correctly (but none of my searches anywhere yielded an answer).

I'll try my best to explain;

I've created an Applescript that is used in a mail client (Mac Mail and MS Outlook).

Basically when an email is recieved, it checks the subject, if the subject contains "whatever" then the script executes.

This script asks if you'd like to send an auto-response. If you click no, nothing happens. If you click yes, one is sent. Simple enough right?

Well, the problem I ran into is 20 people all said yes at the same time, sending 20 auto-generated emails.

I am attempting to find SOMEWAY to have "it" check to see if someone has already clicked yes. Does anyone have any insight? Am I going too far outside the scope of Applescript? If so, any alternatives would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need some centralized way to keep track when a yes is clicked. So a simple text file on the server may do the job. What I'm thinking is that when someone clicks yes to send the auto-responce then the first thing the script does is check the central file to see if anyone else has already clicked yes. If the file does have a yes then a new dialog pops up and lets the user know the email was already responded to and of course that yes does not respond. If the file does not have a yes then the script writes a yes for that email to the file, then sends the response.

You would need some way to distinguish between the emails that come in at different times so you would check the central file for this unique email property... something that is unique to each email but the same for everyone that receives it. If there is not a unique property then maybe a time based check would work. For example you could write the time-of-day to the file, and you don't send a response if the file contains a time within 30 minutes or some other suitable time period.

I hope that gives you some ideas. Good luck.